# Filter of my datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, ado.net

I tried this code for filter but not work

My datatable looks like this

```
    ID       Name         Age
    1        Harsh         6
    2        Prasann       5
```

My code:

```
dt = dsDecEjID.Tables(0).select ("Age between 6 and 7")
```

This code causes an error for between condition.

How to add between condition in `datatable.select`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `between` syntax for the `DataView.RowFilter`. You need to change that to:

```
[Age] >= 6 AND [Age] <= 7
```

Comment: Gridview.DataSource = dsDecEjID.Tables(0).Select("[Age] >= 6 AND [Age] <= 7").CopyToDataTable() this gives error source contain datarow

Comment: what can i do for bind select statement to gridview?

Comment: @Harsh, take the resulting `DataTable` and set the `DataSource` of the `GridView`. After setting the `DataSource` call the `DataBind()` method.

Comment: @Harsh, why don't you get started on it, because I've given you the two lines of code you need, and if you're still having trouble then you can ask another question specifically for that code.

Comment: I tried this code dt = dsDecEjID.Tables(0)     GrdMehroomeenReport.DataSource = dsDecEjID.Tables(0).Select("Age between 6 and 7").CopyToDataTable()
                GrdMehroomeenReport.DataBind() how can i make datarow

Answer (score 1):

You can use like

```
string age = "(6,7)";
DataRow[] drow = dsDecEjID.Tables[0].Select("Age between " + age );
```

Comment: i am not using datarow

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
DataRow[] drs = dsDecEjID.Select("Age >= 6 AND Age <= 7");
DataTable dt2 = dsDecEjID.Clone();
 foreach (DataRow d in drs) 
{
    dt2.ImportRow(d);
}
```